# How to use IPython alias for custom python interpreter?

Tags: python, ipython

When launching python in a terminal, one can do `$alias python=ipython` so that python starts with the `IPython` console on launch.

This applies to the system default python interpreter (Anaconda for me).

How can I set this option for other (non-default) python interpreters, such as `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: why do you want to do that? It is potentially breaking python programs because they assume that `python` starts the interpreter and not the ipython shell

Comment: That would not be good. I want to do it to be able to copy/paste indented python into the console without adjustment.

Comment: you want to paste the code **once** you are in the console, right? So why don't you just type `ipython` and then paste the code?

Comment: Right. Typing `ipython` my default python interpreter starts (Anaconda). For some testing I need to use `/usr/bin/python` in some cases. A workaround to start `IPython` using `usr/bin/python` is also welcome :)

Comment: what does `which ipython` say?

Comment: @hansaplast `/Users/pjs/anaconda/bin/ipython`

Comment: can you try `/usr/local/bin/ipython` or `/usr/bin/ipython`? The former is where my ipython is installed